# Trying to remotely execute a string via ssh but my back slash keeps on getting duplicated

Tags: ssh, remote-management

I an trying to pull cpu data on PMD's (Poll Mode Drivers) from remote servers and this is what it should look like:

```
pidstat -t -p `pidof ovs-vswitchd` 1 1 | grep -E pmd\|%CPU
01:48:19 PM   UID      TGID       TID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command
01:48:20 PM   997         -     28553    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    14  |__pmd8
01:48:20 PM   997         -     28555  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00    27  |__pmd9
01:48:20 PM   997         -     28556  100.00    1.00    0.00  100.00    38  |__pmd10
01:48:20 PM   997         -     28557    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    39  |__pmd12
01:48:20 PM   997         -     28558  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     2  |__pmd11
01:48:20 PM   997         -     28559  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00    15  |__pmd14
01:48:20 PM   997         -     28560  100.00    1.00    0.00  100.00     3  |__pmd13
01:48:20 PM   997         -     28561  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00    26  |__pmd15
Average:      UID      TGID       TID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command
Average:      997         -     28553    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     -  |__pmd8
Average:      997         -     28555  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     -  |__pmd9
Average:      997         -     28556  100.00    1.00    0.00  100.00     -  |__pmd10
Average:      997         -     28557    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     -  |__pmd12
Average:      997         -     28558  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     -  |__pmd11
Average:      997         -     28559  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     -  |__pmd14
Average:      997         -     28560  100.00    1.00    0.00  100.00     -  |__pmd13
Average:      997         -     28561  100.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     -  |__pmd15
```

This is the command string I am sending to the remote server:

```
ssh -vvvv  heat-admin@host.com ''pidstat -t -p '`pidof ovs-vswitchd` 1 1 | grep -E pmd\|%CPU'
```

and this is what I am seeing being sent:

```
pidstat -t -p `pidof ovs-vswitchd` 1 1 | grep -E pmd\\|%CPU
```

Everything is correct except for the double back slashes, it should only be a single slash.

Comment: Did you try not using the back-slash and instead surrounding the regexp within double-quotes ? (also leave the single-quotes as they are)

Comment: Thanks Rui. I have tried double quotes to no avail and unfortunately removing the back slash does not produce expected result.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SSH is simply lying on how many backslashes it actually sends to the server. Let us look at some trivial examples:

```
ssh -v juha@goliath 'echo h\ello'
...
debug1: Sending command: echo h\\ello
hello
...
```

```
ssh -v juha@goliath 'echo h\\ello'
...
debug1: Sending command: echo h\\\\ello
h\ello
...
```

```
ssh -v juha@goliath 'echo h\\\ello'
...
debug1: Sending command: echo h\\\\\\ello
h\ello
...
```

```
ssh -v juha@goliath 'echo h\\\\ello'
...
debug1: Sending command: echo h\\\\\\\\ello
h\\ello
...
```

It seems, that SSH passes the quoted command correctly to the remote shell, since the latter outputs exactly what we would have gotten if the commands would have been executed locally.

On the other hand, SSH seems to blindly double the number of backslashes in its debug message. This also holds if one introduces an additional level of quoting like in

```
ssh -v juha@goliath "echo 'h"'\\'"ello'"
...
debug1: Sending command: echo 'h\\\\ello'
h\\ello
...
```

To make the quoting scheme clear for the last example: The last argument in the SSH command is a concatenation of three strings: `"echo 'h"`, `'\\'`, and `"ello'"`. The local shell turns this into `echo 'h\\ello'` prior passing it to SSH.

Now for your command:

```
ssh -vvvv  heat-admin@host.com ''pidstat -t -p '`pidof ovs-vswitchd` 1 1 | grep -E pmd\|%CPU'
```

You have two single quotes in front of `pidstat`. This causes `pidstat -t -p` to be unquoted, but this should do no harm. Therefore, and from the above, it is quite likely that the remote shell correctly receives the last argument to `grep` as `pmd\|%CPU` turning it into the extended regexp `pmd|%CPU` which is passed to `grep` as desired.

So, if this does not work as expected, it has probably another reason than the number of backslashes.

You can verify this by avoiding backslashes at all, for example like so:

```
ssh -v heat-admin@host.com 'pidstat -t -p `pidof ovs-vswitchd` 1 1 | grep -E '"'pmd|%CPU'"
```

Here the last argument is a concatenation of two strings: `` 'pidstat -t -p `pidof ovs-vswitchd` 1 1 | grep -E ' `` and `"'pmd|%CPU'"`. The local shell turns this into `` pidstat -t -p `pidof ovs-vswitchd` 1 1 | grep -E 'pmd|%CPU' `` and passes this to SSH.